# Phonegap vertical scroll

Tags: cordova

I am building a phonegap app for ios and have vertical scroll issue. There appears to be a few pixels scroll in the webview even without any content and this is affecting my absolutely positioned nav bar and tab bar built in html

Here is the html page I have - there is no content by I still get the scroll amount shown in the image:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="scripts/vendor/cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[scroll screenshot http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/5140/screenshot20130225at212.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/5140/screenshot20130225at212.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
```

And in config.xml:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Above are settings I found to be the best start for handling scroll on iOS.  Then, just add 'overflow: auto' to any element you need to scroll.  Use overthrow or iscroll to help support iOS < 5, android < 3, and and so on.

Comment: Excellent! That seems to have fixed that little issue. I was almost ready to give up on phonegap entirely - been trying to find a fix for this for weeks

Answer (score 7):

This solved it for me (on iOS at least - may have other compatibility things on other platforms)

Try removing `width=device-width, height=device-height` from your meta at the top.

It's an issue with the device not factoring for the status bar at the top as far as I can tell.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for this. Lost an evening trying to find it. Peskt device-height. Serves me right for pasting in a suggested meta-tag without studying it properly.

Answer (score 1):

For a latest answer (as of 2016), this solution was the most effective (smooth scrolling) for me in Cordova iOS.

```
.element {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Source: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

Answer (score 0):

None of above fixed my problem but below link. In my case, there was an excessive gap below the content which could not be explained and this gap was causing the scrollbar.

Here is the link:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Prevent-Scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the System Tray, it did the trick for me.

On MainPage.xaml, set "IsVisible" to false.

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
```

Answer (score -2):

This might help:

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi I have tried that, It seems like even a fresh install of phonegap has this issue.