# Phonegap vertical scroll issue

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a phonegap app for android and have a vertical scroll issue. It is  similar to [Phonegap vertical scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076873/phonegap-vertical-scroll). I use and fix on android 2.3 but it happen on another phone using android 4.0. You can see video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SADCFRoxj4s at 00:10. How can i do to removing it and highlight when pull the scroll?

p/s : it still happen on the build for IOS. I use phonegap build online to build it

Comment: what you want to remove

Comment: it seams your html content size is not proper according to webview. please change size of html container size and check.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati i want to remove the scroll and the highlight

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove highlight?

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

You want to remove scrollbar? Adjust you container to fit webview size. If you have no luck with this you can still try to hack into the android webview and disable scrolling

```
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Read:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid/

http://daneden.me/2011/12/putting-up-with-androids-bullshit/